How to create a hyperlink in Typescript file? Angular 16+
I have a consts.ts file in my project, now.. I have
export const LINK1 = <a href='https://sample.com/'>LINK 1</a>;
It doesn't work. I want to have a hyperlink text which is "LINK 1"
export const LINK1 = `<a href='https://sample.com/'>LINK 1</a>`;

I want to have a hyperlink text which is "LINK 1"

Please look at this answer also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41675806/1792984

export const LINK1 = "<a href='https://sample.com/'>LINK 1</a>";, see that you always can enclosed an expression with singles quotes using double quotes -viceverse is true also-

Instead of storing the actual html in the string, why not just store the URL in the constants.
export const LINK1 = 'https://sample.com/';

Then in the component you can store this in a variable and use it on the HTML.
TS
import { LINK1 } from './path-to-constants';
...

...
@Component({ ... });
export class SomeComponent {
    link = LINK1;
    ...
    

HTML:
<a [href]="link">LINK 1</a>


If you definetly want to store the HTML as a string, then you can use [innerHTML] to convert the string to HTML.
The downside of this approach is that, angular features like property binding, event binding do not work using this method.
CONSTANTS
export const LINK1 = '<a href='https://sample.com/'>LINK 1</a>';

TS
import { LINK1 } from './path-to-constants';
...

...
@Component({ ... });
export class SomeComponent {
    link = LINK1;
    ...
    

HTML:
<span [innerHTML]="link"></span>


I don't see a good reason that LINK1 is a constant. In my opinion, as you've chosen Angular for a development framework, LINK1 should be a component. So, you could use it wherever you want like <app-link1 />, and it will be handled properly and safely by the framework.
Here is an example component
// link1.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-link1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './link1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./link1.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Link1Component {}

<!-- link1.component.html -->
<a href='https://sample.com/'>LINK 1</a>

<!-- example usage of the component -->
...
<app-link1 />
...

This way you have the flexibility to expose the href and the link text as inputs whenever you want.
